# Why does Net::SNMP give errors when I use -privkey with SNMPv3?

Tags: perl, snmp

I'm trying to modify a script that uses SNMPv2 to use SNMPv3 instead, using the [Net::SNMP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SNMP) module.

```
#Define SNMP session
($session, $error) = Net::SNMP->session(
 -hostname     => shift || $hostname,
 -version      => "snmpv3",
 -username     => "user",
 -authprotocol => "md5",
 -authkey      => "password123",
 -privprotocol => "des",
 -privkey      => "password123"
);
```

When I do the above, I get a complaint that the private key is not in hex:

```
The privKey "password123" is expected in hexadecimal format
```

So I do a hex conversion:

```
$privkey = unpack "H*", "password123";
```

But then I receive a complaint about the length of the string:

```
The CBC-DES privKey length of 10 is invalid, expected 16
```

Anyone offer any advice? I'm trying to be security conscious and use SNMPv3 but it's causing so many headaches that I'm tempted to just can it and go back to 2c.

Oh, this also works flawlessly on the CLI when just doing an snmpwalk/snmpget with the exact same credentials.

Comment: Does `$privkey = unpack "H16", "password123";` make any difference?

Comment: Similar error: The CBC-DES privKey length of 8 is invalid, expected 16

Answer (score 1):

From the [Net::SNMP documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SNMP#User-based-Security-Model-Arguments):

> Optionally, the `-authkey` argument can be used so that a plain text password does not have to be specified in a script. The `-authkey` argument expects a hexadecimal string produced by localizing the password with the authoritativeEngineID for the specific destination device. The snmpkey utility included with the distribution can be used to create the hexadecimal string (see [snmpkey](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-SNMP/snmpkey.PL)).
>
> [...]
>
> The `-privkey` and `-privpassword` arguments expect the same input as the `-authkey` and `-authpassword` arguments respectively.

The [snmpkey](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-SNMP/snmpkey.PL) utility uses both the password *and* an SNMPEngineID (an identifier associated with each SNMP entity) to create the key, so simply converting your password to hex won't work.

Answer (score 0):

just use -authpassword, -privpassword in place of -authkey, -privkey